# How to make wrapper of full height of page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wrapper

please visit http://appkify.com, its wordpress site.

When you click on Categories tab, the height of wrapper decreases to content height. Is theire any way to make it full height?

I've tried adding following property but it then making body background to come as a border for all posts.

```
html,body, #wrapper {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Try just having html, body {height:100%;) then add height:100% to the #wrapper css you already have. I tried this in Firebug and it worked.

Comment: Its working but then the footer text gets hide after saving.

Comment: I just confirmed what Billy noted. That seems to work. You might want to use `#wrapper {min-height: 100%;}` instead of `height` though in case the `wrapper` div exceeds the height of the page.

Comment: Thanks @DavidFaux, the #wrapper {min-height: 100%;} worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapper has automatic height. It get's created. And as you write the contents to it gets bigger. However by putting the height as 100%, when the overflow occurs while writing the wrapper it will get scroll bar on your webpage rather then on a browser.